# Error while loggin in facebook through UWP windows 10 app

Tags: c#, windows, facebook, uwp

Am getting the error : ***Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.*** Am trying to login to facebook using a UWP app. The application is using facebook's SDK.
[image]

I have checked that the Facebook ID and Windows SID are the ones which were generated by facebook and the windows store.but am still getting the error. Could anybody help me

Comment: Try to check this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain

Answer (score 2):

I enabled 'Embedded Browser OAuth Login' option and it worked. see image below for the option
[image]