# Facebook Share CallBack response Getting Failed``

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, callback

I am sharing a facebook page on my Timeline and holding a response in a `callback`. But each time it fails and callback response throws following error:

> Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Here is the HTML Element on which I'm calling the method.

```
<a onclick="shareonfacebook()"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>facebook</a>
```

And this is the callback method for my facebook button

```
    function shareonfacebook(){
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'APP ID',
            xfbml      : true,
            version    : 'v2.8'
        });


        FB.ui({
            method: 'share',
            href: 'http://promo.globalhellogroup.com',

        }, function(response){
              if (response && response.post_id) {
                        alert('Post was published.');
                    } else {
                        alert('Post was not published.');
                    }             
  }
        });
    }
```

Response is always that error message.

Comment: Could you specify the `error` parameter in your error callback and tell us which error you are getting back? (`error: function(error){.. console.log(error)..}` instead of alerting a custom string.

Comment: Can't load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

Comment: This error i have got on the dialogue.

Comment: Seems like you've to check the URL settings for the Facebook app (Site URL and OAuth URI). [This SO question could be related to your error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain)

Comment: I tried all solution that are suggested but nothing worked.

Comment: Can you show the screenshot of your settings page on the "Facebook Login" tab from the left sidebar? Also, paste the main domain on which this app is hosted.