# Facebook app domain Android

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, appauth

I keep getting the screen bellow when trying to use Facebook login. I'm trying to use AppAuth for Android ( https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-Android )  it mentions a domain URL but it is an Android app. Trying to use the OAuth2 specifications. Used Auth endpoint "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth" and token endpoint "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/oauth/access_token". Any ideas, of what it could really be. Thanks for the help.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook OAuth "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain)

Comment: I think it is different, he is using a website, I'm using native Android app, no URL exists.

Comment: Is there a reason why you aren't using the Facebook Android SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/ Related: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/05/oauth2-logging-in-facebook/#whats-missing-from-oauth2

Answer (score 0):

Lead maintainer for AppAuth-Android here. Facebook auth isn't directly supported by AppAuth, as they don't support the recommendations of [RFC 8252](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8252). It is possible to make it work, see [my demo](https://github.com/iainmcgin/AppAuth-Demo).

My general recommendation would be to use the [Facebook SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/) if your app does not have an associated website. If the app has an associated site, perform the authentication via your site (in a custom tab) and then pass the necessary auth tokens back to the app.