# Domain is not included in app domain

Tags: android, facebook, appdomain

I am having this issue from couple of Days.Previously it runs quite good but now this is showing above error.I am not able to find out what i am missing?How can this issue be solved?

**image**
[image]

**setting image**
[image]

some portion of **RateReview**

```
  public static String BASE_DOMAIN = "http://www.facebook.com";
  public static String PATH_URL = "http://patanheritage.com/homestay/";

     webViewComment.loadDataWithBaseURL(BASE_DOMAIN,
                "<html><head></head><body><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><div id=\"fb-root\"></div><script>(function(d, s, id) {var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if (d.getElementById(id)) return;js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;js.src = \"http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=" + APP_KEY + "\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script><div class=\"fb-comments\" data-href=\""
                        + PATH_URL + home_stay_id + "\" data-width=\"470\"></div> </body></html>", "text/html", null, null);
        webViewComment.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientActivity());
```

**stacktrace**

```
 "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.", source: https://www.facebook.com/connect/ping?client_id=175417393005037&domain=www.facebook.com&origin=2&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaticxx.facebook.com%2Fconnect%2Fxd_arbiter%2Fr%2FZ2duorNoYeF.js%3Fversion%3D42%23cb%3Dfd183e7266bb3c%26domain%3Dwww.facebook.com%26origin%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Ff3595cf4c5a55c8%26relation%3Dparent&response_type=token%2Csigned_request%2Ccode&sdk=joey (1)
10-08 07:48:34.325 1404-1424/? W/audio_hw_generic: Hardware backing HAL too slow, could only write 0 of 720 frames
```

> how can this issue be solved???

Comment: You are showing us a screenshot that has the field name "App Domains" completely empty, and are asking us what the error message could mean ...?

Comment: @CBROE it worked previously without adding appDomain?? why that worked, that should not have to work out previously ,as you said.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I am having the same error and I *do* have my application's domain in the App Domain field.

Comment: @dwilliss sorry bro i  just forgot .