# How to fix localhost Facebook apps “Error: Can’t Load URL: The domain of this URL isn’t included in the app’s domains”

Tags: html, facebook, oauth, facebook-javascript-sdk

I know that this question has been asked previously in this link [Facebook OAuth "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain) , but the solution is not working for me and it doesn't strictly similar to my issue.
I'm trying to setup Facebook OAuth to work with my application that is being developed locally on my machine.

I followed every steps from facebook guide:

1. I created my application
2. I added a web platform with the url http://localhost/
3. I added Product Facebook Login
4. I added code for Continue with Facebook button described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button) in my html page

Facebook button is on my page but it doesn't work when I click on it (Error: Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app’s domains).

I tried to add a domain (localhost, http://localhost, http://localhost:5000) but it didn't work.

I then added http://localhost:5000/ to the field 'Valid OAuth redirect URIs', but no improvement.

Here my Facebook login settings :
[login setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IsBpE.png)

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: If your local test setup runs on port 5000, maybe add that port in the web platform URL settings. Valid OAuth redirect URIs should not be relevant here, since this is not about the server-side login flow in the first place. Also check in the Facebook Login settings section, which types of login you’re actually allowing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Adding port in the web platform URL settings doesn't work. My type of login are in my post (I just added it)