# "Facebook OAuth" The domain of this my domain isn't included in the app's domain how to add it?

Tags: laravel, facebook-login

when i try to set up login with facebook i keep getting this error

Can't load URL
The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and sub-domains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings. 
ps:i try a lot of solution on stackoverflow and other website

Comment: This post has several upvoted answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain .

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ i try those solutions thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Facebook OAuth "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain)

Comment: @not yet sure i'm still trying

Comment: i foud the problem was the redirect url 'facebook' => [
        'client_id'     => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
        'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
        'redirect'      => 'https://maroc-emplois.net/', (i was using env('url_redirect')
    ],