# cannot load url error in facebook login using node in localhost

Tags: node.js, facebook-login

I know there are lot of posts and blogs regarding this error but most of the answers were related to the wrong url in the OAuth Redirect URIs and have tried all of them.
Currently I trying to login with facebook on my localhost only.

[image]

any help would be appreciated as I am struck here for a long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i was able to resolve it. I added the test app by clicking on the option button of the my app and then creating test app for it.

Answer (score 0):

In oauth2 (google, facebook, linkedin, etc) there are 2 parameters that need to be configured:

- domain or origin
- redirect or callback

In Facebook App Settings we have:

---

## App Domain (Your problem)

**sample:** acme.com

The domain should be without "https" or "www" or "subdomain":

[image: fb]

---

## Site URL

**sample:** http://acme.com/

---

## OAuth redirect URI

**sample:** http://acme.com/auth/facebook/callback

**/auth/facebook/callback** must be a route in your nodejs express.

## Advice

Review char by char the explained values in your facebook configuration page.

## Source

- https://help.sharetribe.com/en/articles/1317484-how-to-solve-the-can-t-load-url-the-domain-of-this-url-isn-t-included-in-the-app-s-domains-facebook-login-error
- [Facebook OAuth "The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domain"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37063685/facebook-oauth-the-domain-of-this-url-isnt-included-in-the-apps-domain)