# Facebook Login :Can't Load URL The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains when using login with facebook-android-sdk in android studio

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk

By following the documentation of **facebook SDK for android** I have this issue :

***Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.***

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37075525/10980926) answer help?

Comment: no it does not help , this was for web facebook sdk , the http must be https for new facebook sdk , but mine was disabling Future off-Facebook Activity in facebook app settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution of my problem , it may help other developers :

i was disabling the **Future off-Facebook Activity** so that causes me the problem , so enabling it fix the my issue.

you can change it by navigating to ***settings -> Off-Facebook Activity -> Manage your Off-Facebook Activty***

Then click on the right top 3 dots then click on **Mange Future Activity** in the bottom sheet dialog menu then click on the button **Mange Future Activty** located in the bottom of the page then disable **Future Off-Facebook Activty**